# Changing dataframe values as columns - columns - as index

Tags: python, pandas

meet the problem of changing values and columns names,

for example i have such Pandas dataframe:

```py
       Value  2013  2014 Company Name
1  Employees    10    12     Aviators
2  Computers    20     2     Aviators
3  Employees     4    13       Mouses
4  Computers     1     8       Mouses
5   Monitors     5     1       Mouses
```

and i need to make values as colums and years as values or indexes (values better) smth like this:

```py
      Employees  Computers  Monitors Company name
2013         10         20       NaN     Aviators
2014         12          2       NaN     Aviators
2013          4          1       5.0       Mouses
2014         13          8       1.0       Mouses
```

So i need only change years and values, company Name column should be placed like on the sample

What's the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Using [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['Company Name'], 
                    columns='Value',
                    aggfunc='sum').stack(level=0).reset_index(level=0)

Value Company Name  Computers  Employees  Monitors
2013      Aviators       20.0       10.0       NaN
2014      Aviators        2.0       12.0       NaN
2013        Mouses        1.0        4.0       5.0
2014        Mouses        8.0       13.0       1.0
```

To remove the column index name, use `rename_axis`:

```
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis='columns')

     Company Name  Computers  Employees  Monitors
2013     Aviators       20.0       10.0       NaN
2014     Aviators        2.0       12.0       NaN
2013       Mouses        1.0        4.0       5.0
2014       Mouses        8.0       13.0       1.0
```

Comment: It gaves me DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: Edited my answer with `aggfunc='sum'`, can you try that @George

Comment: Let's see if this works first, he might have `datetime` columns instead. @jezrael

Comment: With aggfunc it works, but thats the difference between sum and first?

Comment: @George - it means data are not numeric, so solution failed. sum is not good options here, because if concanecate numbers like `'1' + '2'` = `12`. If use `first`, then get data lost, `'2'` is removed.

Comment: And how to make years not as index - as DataFrame column and add indexes 0-1-2-3-4-5 etc

Comment: Remove `level=0` from `reset_index`, so simply use `reset_index()` at the end @George

Comment: @jezrael it is for OP to decide what kind of aggregation function he wants to use. This is not clear from the example. So `sum` or `first` or something else.

Comment: @Erfan - do you want add some data sample for explain difference?

Comment: Yes, will do later @jezrael